# javascript css without frameworks

Tags: javascript, css

I want to build a left sidebar that opens content in the right div when you click on a link without using a framework such as jquery.

Can you point me to a resource for this. I haven't been able to find a decent resource in Dynamic Drive or Google.

Also, I need resources to build other javascript and css tools without using frameworks.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why don't you want to use frameworks? they are sets of common helpful code, that developers should reuse so they don't keep reinventing the wheel every time.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to reinvent a bicycle (i.e. not use any js frameworks)? Just curious...

Comment: @bluefoot: My guess is a requirement passed down from draconian corporate IT. :P

Comment: @bluefoot: you beat me with the bicycle! :)

Comment: Frames still suck, even if you fake them with JavaScript.

Comment: @Andrey no reason at all. and not use frameworks is, most of the time, reinventing things and losing time :)

Answer (score 0):

For the left opening content in the right, you can set the left links to change the css of the right containers so they can be opened, something like:

```
<a rel="leftlink" onclick="openContent('content-2')>LInk 2</a>

<div id="content-2" class="visibility: hidden">I am a second right content</div>
```

And the js function should be:

```
function openContent(el_id) {
    document.getElementById(el_id).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Once again, you will spend less time (and consequently less money) using a framework such as jQuery...

Comment: While this will *work*, I'd like to suggest that my own interpretation of the requirements is that he wants to *load* content *into* the right `div` by clicking a link in the left `div`. Simulating `frames`, if you will, rather than making an existing element visible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to have an iframe on the right and a left div with links that affect the iFrame?

To do this, you only have to change the "src" attribute of an iFrame element.
example:

      `var iFrameElement = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
      iFrameElement.setAttribute("src",new_page_source);`


You would have to attach events to the links, and those events to change the attribute of the iFrameElement.
Some resources:
http://ajaxian.com/archives/sandboxing-javascript-with-iframes
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Working-with-IFRAME-in-JavaScript/
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/